# Regex to eliminate a part of string inside array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell

I have an array of strings, and I would like to eliminate part of each string in that array, but I have trouble with Regex.

Format of the each string is the following:

```
username  comment  IPaddress
username2 comment  IPaddress
```

Unfortunately, on some lines, I have more than one space between username and comment. Also, there is at least one space, but sometimes more between comment and IP address. My idea is to start at the position of the first space and to delete everything up to IP address which is in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format. Also, trick there is that somewere I have a default route (0.0.0.0) so I would also need to check that first octet of the IP address have one up to three digits before dot. 
Output should just be, for every line

```
username IPaddress
```

with one space.

When I do `$array.GetType()` this is what I get

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                         
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

I guess `-replace` should help me, but all of my Regex results fail miserably.

Comment: can you provide examples for the default route? Also, do you want to skip them?

Comment: No, I don't, I want to delete the comments for every line.
Here is one of the examples
`jdoe   (comment missing) 0.0.0.0`
`jdoe2 This is jdoe2           192.168.0.1`
I just want everything from last char in the username (or everything from first space up to the IP address to be deleted, so I only have
`jdoe 0.0.0.0`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex could look like this:

```
^(\w+).*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wmYy7Q2mtn6kyC1v)

Now you can capture the username and IP and replace the whole string with these:

```
$test= @(
    'jdoe (comment missing) 0.0.0.0'
    'jdoe2 This is jdoe2 192.168.0.1'
)


$test -replace '^(\w+).*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', '$1 $2'
```

**Output:**

```
jdoe 0.0.0.0
jdoe2 192.168.0.1
```